# How to add timestamp to sent and received message like whatsapp in Chatto

Tags: ios, swift

I have done messaging app using Chatto which supports image and text sending, but I don't know how to put timestamp to sent and received messages like whatsapp using chatto.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UTC timestamp to manage the send and receive time of message.

1) First approach is take timezone from user and give it local time in messages.

2) Send UTC time in message body and device will calculate the Local time based on current device timezone.

Comment: Ok thanks. But how to display the messaged time in Chatto for every conversation.